# android camera2 API - how to set zoom out to ultra wide

Tags: android, android-camera2

I trying to **zoom out** (wide lens to ultrawide lens) using Camera2 API on Android, but I don't understand how to find the correct `Rect()` for `SCALER CROP REGION` combine with `CONTROL ZOOM RATIO` to be ultrawide because changing the `CONTROL ZOOM RATIO` to `0.5f` doesn't work and to `2.0f"` make zoom in and not a zoom out.

I do my test on **XIAOMI MI 10 LITE 5G**

```
characteristics.get( CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE );  //Rect(0, 0 - 4000, 3000)
characteristics.get( CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM );  //10.0
Range<Float> zoomRange = characteristics.get( CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO_RANGE );  //[1.0, 10.0]
```

The doc for CONTROL ZOOM RATIO: [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO)

Example of using Camera2 API : [Here](https://gitlab.com/testonull1/cam2api/-/tree/master)

**EDIT** :

[image: wide]

[image: ultrawide]

Answer (score 1):

If `CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO_RANGE` returns a minimum value of 1.0, then zooming out is not supported on that device, even if it has a ultrawide lens.

Unfortunately, many manufacturers have yet to allow applications to access the ultrawide (or telephoto) cameras via the camera APIs. And only allow access in the default camera app they develop.

Comment: it's little weird because the basic camera app have a ultrawide function (example in my edit), maybe you're right the tech isn't ready yet (Control zoom ratio is add in api 30)

Comment: Yes, manufacturers make the functionality available to their own app, but haven't made it robust enough to make it available to other apps.